Is the divergence of X the same on all surfaces?
Suppose we have a regular surface S with a riemannian metric g, a differentiable vector field X : S->R^3.There are two definitions of Divergence of X:
First for all p in S we have the covariant differential of X:
It is the Endomorphism  F : TpS ->TpS. F takes a vector v in TpS, then the differential (vector) dX(p)(v) of X on the point p in the direction of v, then the orthogonal projection of dX(p)(v) on TpS.
The Divergence of X is then defined as the trace of this Endomorphism (of the matrix).
The other definition of Divergence is the sum of the derivatives:
If X = $\Sigma$ qi $\frac{dF}{dui}$ with a local parametrization F of S (if det(gkl)=1) then div(X) = $\Sigma$ $\frac{dqj}{dj}$
This sounds similar to the well known definition in physics: div(X) =  $\frac{dX}{dx}$+$\frac{dX}{dy}$+$\frac{dX}{dz}$.
If I take S = S^2 , point p = (0,0,1) and X(x,y,z) = (x,y,z) then with the first definition I get F(1,0,0)=(1,0,0), F(0,1,0)=(0,1,0) because TpS is parallel to the xy plane. So div(X) = 2
I haven't tried the second definition yet.
With the third definition on the same vector field X, same point p we get div(X)=1+1+1=3 not 2
So the third definition does not apply for all surfaces S? Why do I get 2 with the first and 3 with the third definition?
Other question: If I take the same point p, same Vector field X:S->R^3 but different surfaces S, does div(x)(p) have to stay the same? TpS is different so the projection should be different. Does someone have an example where div gives different values on the same point p? Or is it always the same?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Welcome to MSE! <> The third definition is not the divergence of a vector field on a surface, but in an open region of three-space. Perhaps relatedly, the last paragraph technically makes no sense: A vector field on a surface $S$ is a mapping whose domain is $S$. Speaking of "the same vector field on two different surfaces" is a fundamental contradiction in terms.
